# Difficulty setting focus on newly created object in javascript

Tags: javascript, focus

So, related to an earlier question, but forgive me for my naive javascript ways. Basically I now want to automatically bring a text input into focus when it is added to the DOM. Part of me thinks that I might be trying to add focus to the object before it exists, but I'm not quite sure how I would go about fixing it. Right now this is my relevant code:

```
var searchWrapper = document.createElement("div");
searchWrapper.id = "search-wrapper";

this.parentNode.replaceChild(searchWrapper, this);
document.getElementById("search-wrapper").focus();
```

But it's not quite working. Should I be setting focus as a callback on replaceChild, or is there some other way to do this?

Comment: A `div` can't receive focus, unless you won't add a `tabindex` to it.

Comment: yes, try changing your div into **input** or **a**

Comment: @Teemu Thanks so much, didn't know that and fixed accordingly and now it works great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

<kbd>**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Hs6H3/1/)**</kbd>

```
var searchOrig = document.getElementById("search-wrapper"); 

var searchWrapper = document.createElement("div");
searchWrapper.id = "search-wrapper";
searchWrapper.setAttribute('tabindex', '0'); 

searchOrig.parentElement.replaceChild(searchWrapper, searchOrig);
document.getElementById("search-wrapper").focus();
```

Comment: Oh, awesome, even better! Out of curiosity, where does that focus border get defined? Is that something just automatically generated?

Comment: It is part of the [outline](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_outline.asp) property in css. You can set it via `div:focus { outline:2px solid blue !important; }`